# Parsley JS - Disable message for individual validator

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, parsley.js

Currently I have two custom validators one triggers the other and I only need to show the error message for one of these validators.

I know you can disable all messages with `data-parsley-errors-messages-disabled` but is there a way to disable the message for an individual validator in Parsley?

**See example here - http://jsfiddle.net/tp9esyt0/1/**

---

JS:

```
window.Parsley.addValidator('ccexp', {
  validate: function(values, id) {
    if($('#' + id + '_month').val() == '' || $('#' + id + '_year').val() == '') {
      return false
    }

    return true
  },
  messages: {
    en: 'Please provide both month and year'
  }
})

window.Parsley.addValidator('ccexpLink', {
  validate: function(values, id) {
    $('#' + id + '_month').parsley().validate()
    return $('#' + id + '_month').parsley().validate() == true ? true : false
  },
  messages: {
    en: ' '  // <-- Howto disable this message completley
  }
})

$('#myform').parsley().on('form:submit', function() {
  return false
})
```

---

Html:

```
<form id="myform">
<select name="month" id="exp_month" data-parsley-validate-if-empty data-parsley-trigger="change" data-parsley-ccexp="exp">
  <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
  <option value="01">01 - Jan</option>
  <option value="02">02 - Feb</option>
  <option value="03">03 - Mar</option>
  <option value="04">04 - Apr</option>
  <option value="05">05 - May</option>
  <option value="06">06 - Jun</option>
  <option value="07">07 - Jul</option>
  <option value="08">08 - Aug</option>
  <option value="09">09 - Sep</option>
  <option value="10">10 - Oct</option>
  <option value="11">11 - Nov</option>
  <option value="12">12 - Dec</option>
</select>
<select name="year" id="exp_year" data-parsley-validate-if-empty data-parsley-trigger="change" data-parsley-ccexp-link="exp">
  <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
  <option value="2016">2016</option>
  <option value="2017">2017</option>
  <option value="2018">2018</option>
  <option value="2019">2019</option>
  <option value="2020">2020</option>
  <option value="2021">2021</option>
  <option value="2022">2022</option>
  <option value="2023">2023</option>
  <option value="2024">2024</option>
  <option value="2025">2025</option>
  <option value="2026">2026</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" />
```

Comment: Why are you calling a validate() in "ccexpLink" custom validator ?

Comment: The `ccexpLink` validator doesn't need to do anything other than trigger the `ccexp` validator as the two fields depend on each other. I'm open to suggestions to a better approach

Answer (score 0):

One better approach is to consider a wrapper of both fields to be the field you are attaching the custom validation to. I'd like this to be formalized but haven't done it yet. Check [this example](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/examples/custom-validator-events.html).

Another alternative approach is to insure that a change in your second field triggers validation in the first one. There's no builtin way to do this yet, but you can do it manually, e.g.:

```
$('.second-field').on('input', function() {
  $('.first-field').trigger('input')
} )
```